# OBIEE RPD reusability in OAS and OAC

Tags: obiee

May I know if RPD developed for OBIEE is reusable in OAC (Oracle Analytics Cloud) and OAS (Oracle Analytics Server) without any glitch or change? I was told by some experts that it is reusable , however wanted to cross validate if there is some required change or condition to be able to reuse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yee-ish". Depends on which version you're coming from and how badly things were done in the legacy version. I just gave a webinar on the subject:

Edit: Oracle doesn't allow direct linking, sorry.

First, go to the hub: https://go.oracle.com/analyticscommunity

From there search for "OAS Upgrade" or use the direct link. It will work whne you have a valid cookie.

https://gateway.on24.com/wcc/eh/2258334/lp/2587842/upgrading-from-obiee-to-oas-the-benefits-the-path-to-modernising-your-analytics-gianni-ceresa-datalysis-christian-berg-dimensionality

Comment: Thanks Chris, Not found, facing below error while opening the URL shared by you:

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. Just saw that direct linking only works with a valid cookie.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above, we recently migrated from OBIEE12214 to OAS and there were only a few issues in Migration. About RPD there was no issue we were able to use it just like that. Notice Repository Versions between the OAS and OBIEE12214 They are the same 356!
[image]
[image]

A tip when you do the BAR file migration from 12214 in the RPD the username and password for the connection pools are lost. Best advise is open the 12C rpd and save it using OAS Admintool and then upload it to OAS.